# Custom form not taking over as default

Tags: list, custom-form

I am on SharePoint 2010 and when I edit a form for a custom list on the site (from the Edit Form button under the list pane) I can edit the form and publish it but it does not take over as the default form for that list type. The form can be viewed under Form Web parts and appears under the heading of Content Type forms. But when clicking on a list entry it still uses the old form.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you select the form, the ribbon should have a button that says Set as default. Click that to set your form as the default and it should then become the new edit form for your list.